# g++ -E option output

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, g++, c-preprocessor

Using this option I receive files after preprocessing. There are many lines like:

```
# 91 "/usr/include/stdint.h" 3 4
```

What do the numbers mean? First I thought that `#91` is the number of line where file is included, but that is not it. And about `3 4` I have no idea at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the official documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html), the line is of the format:

```
# linenum filename flags
```

The `linenum` specifies that the following line originated in `filename` at that line number. Then there are four flags:

- `1` - Start of a new file
- `2` - Returning to a file
- `3` - System header file
- `4` - Treat as being wrapped in `extern "C"`

So let's interpret your linemarker:

```
# 91 "/usr/include/stdint.h" 3 4
```

The following line originated from line 91 of `/usr/include/stdint.h`. It is a system header file and should be treated as wrapped in `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 6):

These are called "line markers". From the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html):

> Source file name and line number information is conveyed by lines of the form
>
> ```
> # linenum filename flags
> ```
>
> These are called linemarkers. They are inserted as needed into the output (but never within a string or character constant). They mean that the following line originated in file filename at line `linenum`. `filename` will never contain any non-printing characters; they are replaced with octal escape sequences.
>
> After the file name comes zero or more flags, which are `‘1’`, `‘2’`, `‘3’`, or `‘4’`. If there are multiple flags, spaces separate them. Here is what the flags mean:
>
> - `‘1’` -
>     This indicates the start of a new file.
> - `‘2’` -
>     This indicates returning to a file (after having included another file).
> - `‘3’` -
>     This indicates that the following text comes from a system header file, so certain warnings should be suppressed.
> - `‘4’` -
>     This indicates that the following text should be treated as being wrapped in an implicit `extern "C"` block.

Answer (score 1):

There are flags (space separated) and the meaning is:

```
1 - Start of a new file
2 - Returning to previous file
3 - Following text comes from a system header file (#include <> vs #include "")
4 - Following text should be treated as being wrapped in an implicit extern "C" block.
```