# Is preprocessor output file a valid C/C++ file

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have 2 files as qwe.h

```
#ifndef QWE_H
#define QWE_H
//#include <iostream>
int asd();
#endif
```

qwe.cc

```
#include "qwe.h"
int asd()
{
std::cout<<"asdasd";
}
```

Running preprocessor only as `g++ -E qwe.cpp > op4`
gives following output

```
# 1 "qwe.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command line>"
# 1 "qwe.cpp"
# 1 "qwe.h" 1




int asd();
# 2 "qwe.cpp" 2
int asd()
{
 std::cout<<"asdasd";
}
```

Shouldn't preprocessor output be a valid **C**/C++ file ?
what is meaning of statements "# int string int"

Comment: possible duplicate of [g++ -E option output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679756/g-e-option-output)

Comment: @djf thanks , should have googled "g++ -E option output" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCC makes a reasonable effort to make the preprocessor output dump still be valid source code. But the general answer is no, it's not intended for that purpose.

You can also pass the `-P` option along with `-E` to make it more machine-readable, and less human-readable. More whitespace will be stripped and the `# 234 "blah.h"` markers won't appear.

> Shouldn't preprocessor output be a valid c/c++ file?

A big part of what the preprocessor does is lexing, or division of source into tokens. Then it expands macros, which generate tokens and whitespace according to certain rules. It's possible for a macro to generate tokens not separated by whitespace. According to the standard, preprocessor output rendered directly as text would not generally be possible to divide back into the correct tokens.

GCC goes an extra mile to try to satisfy the expectation that preprocessor output can be expressed as text, by introducing more whitespace, but it's not really a good thing to rely on, and certainly not portable to other compilers.

Answer (score 6):

They are line numbers used to track where files are included within other files, which is useful when generating compiler warnings and errors.

See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Special_macros_and_directives) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

There's no language requirement for the preprocessor output to be valid C++ -- or even for the output of the preprocessor to be available. But the preprocessor that g++ uses typically (perhaps always?) generates output that can itself be compiled as C++.

> what is meaning of statements `# int string int`?

Any line starting with `#` is a *preprocessing directive*. If the token following the `#` is not otherwise recognized, the part of the line after the `#` is a *non-directive*. (Despite the name, a *non-directive* is a preprocessing directive.) Non-directives are generally ignored.

Normally it's the preprocessor that handles all preprocessing directives, including non-directives, but in this case some lines starting with `#` are passed through to the compiler proper, which knows to ignore them.

You can demonstrate this by feeding the preprocessor output to the compiler:

```
g++ -E foo.cpp > foo_preprocessed.cpp
g++ -c foo_preprocessed.cpp
```

If `foo.cpp` has preprocessor directives, particularly `#include` directives, `foo-preprocessed.cpp` will probably be *much* bigger -- but the compiler will still be able to handle it.

The language standard defines the preprocessor output in terms of tokens, not tex, but it permits enough flexibility so that text is a valid way to represent the required tokens sequence.

(All this applies to C as well as to C++.)